# I haven't overridden show method of xyz interface in demo class, so why is this working?

Tags: java-8

```
public class Demo extends xyz implements abc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        abc a = new Demo();
        xyz x = new Demo();
        Demo w = new Demo();

        a.show();
        x.show();
        w.show();

    }

}

interface abc {
    void show();

}

class xyz {
    public void show() {

        System.out.println("show of xyz");
    }
}
```

OUTPUT :

> show of xyz
>   show of xyz
>   show of xyz

Comment: [Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)).

Comment: Because Demo is a partial class that extends the class xyz and can be accessed using the interface abc. I think you're thinking of an abstract class rather than a partial or inherited class pal.

Comment: Oh, I missed that inheritance clause lol

Answer (score 2):

As the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) also suggest -

Default methods and abstract methods in interfaces are inherited like instance methods. When the supertypes of a class or interface provide multiple default methods with the same signature, *the Java compiler follows inheritance rules to resolve* the name conflict.

```
a.show(); // the service loader finds the service provider of this service using inheritence
x.show(); // same class 
w.show(); // using super
```

---

The ideal way to implement such design would be to move the `implements` to the parent class.

Comment: I can’t follow you. In all three cases, the object has the type `Demo` and the `show()` method inherited from `xyz` will be invoked. And a “service loader” is not involved, not even remotely…

Comment: @Holger the method is in all three cases is invoked from the `xyz` class, the comments just illustrate how they are resolved internally.

Comment: They are resolved the same way in all three cases, looking for a method `show()` in `Demo` first, going to the superclass `xyz` after not finding it in `Demo` (formally, in practice, `Demo` will have a vtable with the entries of `xyz` copied). If `Demo` had overridden `show()`, then `Demo.show()` was invoked in all three cases. And, as said, there is no such thing as a “service loader” or “service provider” here.

Comment: @Holger Could you please elaborate on *resolved the same way* how are they resolved?

Comment: I already did in the previous comment. Formally, the method is looked up in the *actual class* of the object, which is `Demo` in all cases, going up the hierarchy, finding the method in `xyz`. In practice, a vTable is build for each class after loading, containing all inherited method already, so only a single lookup in the vtable of `Demo` will happen. But that’s just an optimization. In either case, the type of the local variable is irrelevant (the JVM doesn’t even know which types these variables had at compile-time).